# wpdb insert null instead of string

Tags: database, string, null, wordpress

I have a problem with wpdb.

I want to insert something in the database. The query looks like:

```
INSERT INTO `table` (`time`, `days_weekly`, `date`, `date_end`, `last_registration_type`, `last_registration`, `blocked_dates`, `length`, `post_id`) VALUES ('06:30:00', '{1,3}', 0, 0, 'hours', 5, 'a:1:{i:0;s:0:\"\";}', '3', 1794)
```

The result looks liek this: [Result of insert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z0B0V.png)

'days_weekly' is NULL. Why?????

**UPDATE**

[Image of DB structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H64IC.png)

**Insert Query:**

From This:

```
 $result = $wpdb->insert(
    'ct_reservation_dates',
    $insert,
    $format
);
```

To This (When i insert exactly this code in PHP, it works, but not with the code above):

```
$wpdb->insert(
    'table',
    array(
        'time' => '06:30:00',
        'days_weekly' => '{1,3}',
        'date' => 0,
        'date_end' => 0,
        'last_registration_type' => 'hours',
        'last_registration' => 5,
        'blocked_dates' => 'a:1:{i:0;s:0:\"\";}',
        'length' => '3',
        'post_id' => 1794
    ),
    array(
        '%s','%s','%d','%d','%s','%d','%s','%s','%d'
    )
);
```

ATTENTION, other datas-attributes!
var_dump of `$insert`:

```
array(10) {
  ["time"]=>
  string(8) "03:00:00"
  ["days_weekly"]=>
  string(11) "{1,3,4,5}"
  ["date"]=>
  int(1458601200)
  ["date_end"]=>
  int(1466632800)
  ["last_registration_type"]=>
  string(5) "hours"
  ["last_registration"]=>
  string(1) "7"
  ["blocked_dates"]=>
  string(61) "a:3:{i:0;s:0:"";i:1;s:10:"24.03.2016";i:2;s:10:"23.03.2016";}"
  ["length"]=>
  string(1) "6"
  ["post_id"]=>
  int(2142)
}
```

var_dump of `$format`:

```
array(10) {
  [0]=>
  string(2) "%s"
  [1]=>
  string(2) "%s"
  [2]=>
  string(2) "%d"
  [3]=>
  string(2) "%d"
  [4]=>
  string(2) "%s"
  [5]=>
  string(2) "%d"
  [7]=>
  string(2) "%s"
  [8]=>
  string(2) "%s"
  [9]=>
  string(2) "%d"
}
```

Comment: If you do `describe table` what datatype is the `days_weekly` field shown as?

Comment: `days_weekly` is a varchar field on a length of 50... When i copy the sql code and past it on PHPMyAdmin it works. But not on wpdb..

Comment: Can you post your actual wpdb code?

Comment: Your code actually works for me without any glitches; the code inserts `{1,3}` into the field.  Here's a minimal pastebin of the test I ran along with the constructed table: http://pastebin.com/Qd97gdzq -- can you run a minimal test just like that to verify same error behavior?

Comment: `string(11) "{1,3,4,5}"` <-- Well, that looks very suspicious. How is "{1,3,4,5}" eleven characters long? It should be nine. Is it possible that some of your characters aren't what they look like? Or possibly you have some invisible characters in there, like a zero-width space, or something?How is this string getting in your array? Is it hardcoded? Can you try replacing it by retyping in your editor?